# android httppost xml data to server

Tags: android, xml

**i am not able to post xml data to server.i am getting error in executing the request to the server. the error is INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.please help me**

```
    public String uploadfiletoserver(String xml)
                int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000; // = 10 seconds
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                        url_context + "/orders/order");
                try {
                     Log.i("YMApps Res","In try for setting url encoded form");
                    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlString);
                    entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                            "application/xml"));
                    request.setEntity(entity);

                    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    Log.i("YMApps Res","Inside try before execute");
                    return client.execute(request, handler);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    Log.i("YMApps Res","Inside catch execute");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                Log.i("YMApps Res","After try and catch in upload file to server");
                return "";
}
```

Comment: are you sending file or just string content?

Comment: i am sending the string in form of xml.

Comment: then I guess error is correct. server is expecting file and you are sending string, please check that on server

Comment: no sir. its expecting xml only. is the code mentions above is correct?

Comment: because i am getting error in executing the http request.

Comment: xml can be file also or string also. so I am sure it's expecting file

Comment: code is correct to send xml as string